# Windows upgrade using license key

Tags: windows-10

I have to use Windows Subsystem Linux but I could not find the option in my windows. In a previous question I have been told that as my windows is an old version (2016), it has to be updated. Due to some reasons, it can't be updated. Should I buy a new OS or buying a license key will do the work?

[image: IMG:]

Edit: When I check for updates, it says:

> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: The question is unclear. The old license should be valid even if you update it. The light versions which are based on old builds might not work correctly soon.

Comment: You should be able to use the [contact] form at the bottom of the page to request your new (registered) account be merged with your [old account](https://superuser.com/users/1170972/nazia-hossain-khan). What are the "some reasons" it cannot be upgraded? If automatic updates don't work then you can try to install manually using the [installer or media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10). If your copy is not legitimate then you may have to buy a licence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could avoid using Windows Update altogether.

Prepare a flash drive, 8 GB or larger. Make sure you have no important data on it - it will be wiped.

[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10). It's a legitimate Microsoft download. The tool available there will help you prepare a Windows 10 installation USB.

Open the flash drive and find a program called *Setup*. Run it, it will guide you through the upgrade process.